# Understanding SQL queries

Tags: sql-query-store

I'm not an expert in SQL hence this question. We use the below queries and I want to understand how its processed. Same table is used in all queries and what I want to know is is it TOP DOWN approach or BOTTOM UP approach? How to understand this query?

```
CREATE TABLE <tablename1> 
select cr_latest_canumber.CAGID, cr_latest_canumber.GFCID, cast(cr_renewal.FAC_LAST_RENEWAL_DATE as STRING) as FAC_LAST_RENEWAL_DATE , cr_cust_total.CUST_TOTAL_CA_LTM, cr_latest_canumber.ca_number as LATEST_CA_NUMBER, cr_latest_canumber.sponsoring_officer as CA_SPONSORING_OFFICER, cr_latest_canumber.rorc as CA_RORC_PCT, cr_latest_canumber.rorc_bucket as CA_RORC_BUCKET , cr_latest_canumber.ca_segment as CA_CLIENT_SEGMENT from (select S.cagid,S.ca_number,S.sponsoring_officer,S.rorc, S.ca_segment, case
when cast(rorc as decimal(8,2)) <= 10 then "0%-10%"
when cast(rorc as decimal(8,2)) > 10 and  cast(rorc as decimal(8,2)) <= 20 then "10%-20%" 
when cast(rorc as decimal(8,2)) > 20 and  cast(rorc as decimal(8,2)) <= 30 then "20%-30%"
when cast(rorc as decimal(8,2)) > 30 and  cast(rorc as decimal(8,2)) <= 40 then "30%-40%"
when cast(rorc as decimal(8,2)) > 40 and  cast(rorc as decimal(8,2)) <= 50 then "40%-50%"                                          
when cast(rorc as decimal(8,2)) > 50 then ">50%"
else 'null'
end rorc_bucket
FROM
(    select distinct cagid, ca_number, sponsoring_officer, rorc, ca_segment, to_date(from_unixtime(max(ca_booked_date) DIV 1000)), rank() over (partition by cagid order by to_date(from_unixtime(max(ca_booked_date) DIV 1000)) desc) as r
from 
<tablename>
where   

                                           ((ca_type='') or 
                                           (ca_type='' and review_type='') or
                                           (ca_type='' and review_type='') or
                                           (ca_type='' and review_type='') or
                                           (ca_type='' and review_type='') or
                                           (ca_type='' and review_type='') or
                                           (ca_type='' and review_type='') )
                                           ) S where S.r = 1
) cr_latest_canumber  left outer join  
(
select to_date(from_unixtime(max(ca_booked_date) DIV 1000)) as FAC_LAST_RENEWAL_DATE, cagid, gfcid from
 <tablename>
 where
 CREDIT_STATUS IN ('','') and
                                           ((ca_type='') or 
                                           (ca_type='' and review_type='') or
                                           (ca_type='' and review_type='') or
                                           (ca_type='' and review_type='')
 ) group by cagid, gfcid
 ) cr_renewal on  cr_latest_canumber.cagid = cr_renewal.cagid  and cr_latest_canumber.gfcid = cr_renewal.gfcid left outer join
(
select credit.cagid, count(distinct(ca_number)) as CUST_TOTAL_CA_LTM
<tablename> credit, (select report_date_12, report_date from <tablename2> cobdt where row_num=1) cobdt
where
to_date(from_unixtime(ca_creation_date DIV 1000)) between cobdt.report_date_12 and cobdt.report_date
and CREDIT_STATUS NOT IN ('','') 
and credit.cagid = credit.gfcid
group by credit.cagid
) cr_cust_total on cr_renewal.cagid=cr_cust_total.cagid;
```

Comment: You mention that you use these queries but don't specify the context, if this is something you copy/pasted from your work codebase you may want to be careful, you can get into hot water by essentially giving away their intellectual property openly on the internet.

Comment: it is often valuable to inspect the query plans of submitted SQL. It tells you exactly what tables are accessed in what order in order to produce the desired results. Start simply, then add in additional clauses and joins to see how the query plan differs.

Answer (score 0):

To understand the query just split the nested query and run separate to get a clear idea
There are 3 subquery and then left outer join that 3query to generate new table
**Query:1  table1:cr_latest_canumber**

```
select distinct cagid, ca_number, sponsoring_officer, rorc, ca_segment, to_date(from_unixtime(max(ca_booked_date) DIV 1000)), rank() over (partition by cagid order by to_date(from_unixtime(max(ca_booked_date) DIV 1000)) desc) as r
from 
<tablename>
where   

                                           ((ca_type='') or 
                                           (ca_type='' and review_type='') or
                                           (ca_type='' and review_type='') or
                                           (ca_type='' and review_type='') or
                                           (ca_type='' and review_type='') or
                                           (ca_type='' and review_type='') or
                                           (ca_type='' and review_type='') )
                                           ) S where S.r = 1
```

**Query:2 table2:cr_renewal**

```
select to_date(from_unixtime(max(ca_booked_date) DIV 1000)) as FAC_LAST_RENEWAL_DATE, cagid, gfcid from
 <tablename>
 where
 CREDIT_STATUS IN ('','') and
                                           ((ca_type='') or 
                                           (ca_type='' and review_type='') or
                                           (ca_type='' and review_type='') or
                                           (ca_type='' and review_type='')
 ) group by cagid, gfcid
```

**query3: table3:cr_cust_total**

```
select credit.cagid, count(distinct(ca_number)) as CUST_TOTAL_CA_LTM
<tablename> credit, (select report_date_12, report_date from <tablename2> cobdt where row_num=1) cobdt
where
to_date(from_unixtime(ca_creation_date DIV 1000)) between cobdt.report_date_12 and cobdt.report_date
and CREDIT_STATUS NOT IN ('','') 
and credit.cagid = credit.gfcid
group by credit.cagid
```

**Final**

```
CREATE TABLE <tablename1> 
select cr_latest_canumber.CAGID, cr_latest_canumber.GFCID, cast(cr_renewal.FAC_LAST_RENEWAL_DATE as STRING) as FAC_LAST_RENEWAL_DATE , cr_cust_total.CUST_TOTAL_CA_LTM, cr_latest_canumber.ca_number as LATEST_CA_NUMBER, cr_latest_canumber.sponsoring_officer as CA_SPONSORING_OFFICER, cr_latest_canumber.rorc as CA_RORC_PCT, cr_latest_canumber.rorc_bucket as CA_RORC_BUCKET , cr_latest_canumber.ca_segment as CA_CLIENT_SEGMENT from (select S.cagid,S.ca_number,S.sponsoring_officer,S.rorc, S.ca_segment, 
case
when cast(rorc as decimal(8,2)) <= 10 then "0%-10%"
when cast(rorc as decimal(8,2)) > 10 and  cast(rorc as decimal(8,2)) <= 20 then "10%-20%" 
when cast(rorc as decimal(8,2)) > 20 and  cast(rorc as decimal(8,2)) <= 30 then "20%-30%"
when cast(rorc as decimal(8,2)) > 30 and  cast(rorc as decimal(8,2)) <= 40 then "30%-40%"
when cast(rorc as decimal(8,2)) > 40 and  cast(rorc as decimal(8,2)) <= 50 then "40%-50%"                                          
when cast(rorc as decimal(8,2)) > 50 then ">50%" else 'null'
end rorc_bucket
FROM
 (cr_latest_canumber  left outer join 
 cr_renewal on  cr_latest_canumber.cagid = cr_renewal.cagid  and cr_latest_canumber.gfcid = cr_renewal.gfcid left outer join
 cr_cust_total on cr_renewal.cagid=cr_cust_total.cagid);
```